# Using ModelBuilder to intersect point data against multiple polygons?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, dbf, intersect

I'm a novice GIS user and looking to create a model in ModelBuilder that can intersect point data which is a survey data made up of 1000's of individual points in dbf format.

This data will change from week to week, whereas the polygons are fixed areas against a single shapefile which contains 15 polygons.

Ideally, I'd like the tool output to produce a file for every polygon that contains the point data.

e.g. if polygon 6 and polygon 9 contained point data, I'd like a dbf file to be produced for each of these areas.

Comment: Welcome to GIS Stack Exchange! It appears you are on the right track with the use of intersect to arrive at a solution to your need. You will likely get a better response from this site if you can provide details of what you have tried and exactly where you are stuck. A good start may be to try to run tools individually until you get your desired result. Once you know what tools and input/output you need you can compile them with model builder to expedite the process in the future.

Comment: to clarify you want a featureclass of polygons that give the count of the number of points in them, or do you want a featureclass of points with an attribute denoting which polygon the point fell in?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  You appear to have created two accounts which inevitably leads to a frustrating experience for you, potential answerers and reviewers so please follow [these instructions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) ASAP to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you want to create individual shape files of each area. Each shape file contains the points that fall within the geographic borders of that area.

If so, do a ‘spatial join’ first. This will create a separate shapefile of the points with an attribute in which area it is located in. Your points are the target_feature.

Afterwards you use ‘SplitLayersByAttributes’ to create individual shape files (and thus individual .dbf files) to split based on the area name attribute.